# Changing my Action filter class to be a Custom authorization attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Iam working on an asp.net mvc4 web application, and I have the following action filter class, which implement a custom authorization  :-

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]

    public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {

        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // var user = User.Identity.Name; // or get from DB
            int value = 0;
            Repository repository = new Repository();

            if (!repository.can(ADusername,Model,value )) // implement this method based on your tables and logic
            {if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {

                    var viewResult = new JsonResult();
                    viewResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
                    viewResult.Data = (new { IsSuccess = "Unauthorized", description = "Sorry, you do not have the required permission to perform this action." });
                    filterContext.Result = viewResult;
               }
                else
                {
                    var viewResult = new ViewResult();

                    viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml";
                    filterContext.Result = viewResult;
                }

            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

and i am using the actino filter before calling the action methods as follow:-

```
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "Edit", Model = "Router")]
        public ActionResult Create(int? rackid)
        {
```

but i need to chnage the action filter class , to be a class that is driven from the AuthorizeAttribute , so can anyone advice what are the needed steps to do so ?

**EDIT**

I modified my action filter class to use AuthorizeAttribute as follow, but my previous caching problem still happening. as if an authorized user access an action method, then if unauthorized user access the same action method he will be able to read the cached data which he does not have permission on it .... and this was the reson i want to change my action filter to be an authorized attribute. my current authorized attribute is :-

```
public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {

        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Action { get; set; }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {

         // code goes here
            if (!repository.can(ADusername,Model,value )) // implement this method based on your tables and logic
            {
               // filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You cannot access this page");

                if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {

                    var viewResult = new JsonResult();
                    viewResult.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
                    viewResult.Data = (new { IsSuccess = "Unauthorized", description = "Sorry, you do not have the required permission to perform this action." });
                    filterContext.Result = viewResult;
                //    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;

                    //filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult("You cannot access this page");

                }
                else
                {
                    var viewResult = new ViewResult();

                    viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml";
                    filterContext.Result = viewResult;
                }

            }

            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

so is my current approach valid ?, baring in mind that i am returning unauthorized view or JSON based on the request type , instead of returning 401 http response ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool authorized = /* your logic here */;

        if (!authorized) 
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Now, to configure the custom error page ("Unauthorized"), here's what you'd probably need inside your `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
        <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="403" path="/error/403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Now, the routing:

```
routes.Add("Error", new Route("error/{statusCode}",
    new { controller = "Error", action = "Details" }));
```

And finally, the controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(int statusCode)
    {
        return View(new { StatusCode = statusCode });
    }
}
```

Couple of links to study:

- [Custom filters in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/426766/Custom-Filters-in-MVC-Authorization-Action-Result)
- [AuthorizeAttrubte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)
- [HandleUnauthorizedRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but what is the idea of having the ErrorController class ? and can i still return the unauthorized view from the cusotm Iauthorization filter class ??

Comment: Yes, you can, and actually, that would probably be a better approach (no redirects, therefore better for SEO). On the other hand, having a dedicated controller can be useful when you want to encapsulate many error-related actions (e.g. troubleshooting actions, contact form, etc.)

Comment: @johnG I think you should return the proper HTTP status codes (403) from within your authorization filter (e.g. by using `HandleUnauthorizedRequest`) rather than just rendering a view containing an error message. This will not only make the behavior more correct and transparent but will probably also help you fix the problems with the user agent caching your current `200 OK` responses.

Comment: but i need to display custom error messages , either full view if a reuqest if normal http , or to return JSON if the request is ajax request. but retuning 403 will not allow me to do so ?

Comment: It will. You can use `httpErrors` configuration section (with `existingResponse` other than `Replace`) for serving full views and still pass `JsonResult` when the request is made via AJAX (haven't tried the latter myself but remember one of my colleagues doing something similar lately). Just remember to respond with a proper HTTP statuses, don't confuse the user agent ;-)

Comment: But i am not sure how i can send the same 403 or 401 error from my custom authorization filter, but on the web.config to return either partial view or JSON , and if i return 401 error then the iis will automatically display a username and password prompt window ...

Comment: and if i return base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext); then no error message will be displayed instead the user will be prompted to enter a username and password